# Manage caching in a multi locale Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, localization, memcached

In an existing and complex Rails App (3.2) with cache_actions, and fragment caching (Rails.cache.fetch, Rails.cache.delete, caches), what would be a suggest approach to manage caching for different users, with different locales?

1. Add current_user.locale to all cache keys?
2. Add a Proc to the cache_store namespace and create different namespace based on locales?

Other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach to this for now is using a proc that will set the namespace based on the current user session with a fallback to common namespace.